# What's the English term for taking off expired products?

Tags: terminology

I forgot the term, feels like it's at the tip of my tongue.

Imagine that I have a shop, with an expired product, took it off the inventory. Now what do you call that item?

Comment: You are ***pulling expired merchandise***

Comment: deprecated might fit

Comment: You are *writing off* the item. The item is then a *write-off*.

Comment: One shop I work in *culls* anything that's been on the shelf too long. Doing that is *culling* and the items are then said to have been *culled*… in the same way herdsmen *cull* over-populous creatures

Comment: Jim's "pull"  is certainly the jargon that U.S. grocers use for perishables. Those dates that are stamped on a carton of milk are called "pull dates".

Answer (score 1):

Jan Ariel, what you are describing is referred to in retail as 'spoiling' an item or 'spoilage', that is, identifying inventory that for any reason cannot be sold. Products expire, products are damaged, products are returned that cannot be re-sold. It has a special meaning. According to "Accounting Tools", a site for accounting education:

> Spoilage is waste or scrap arising from the production process. The term is most commonly applied to raw materials that have a short life span, such as food used in the hospitality industry. Normal spoilage is the standard amount of waste or scrap that is caused by production, and which is difficult to avoid.

'Spoiled' products need not  be literally rotten. Excluding theft, it's the merchandise that a retailer pays for but doesn't sell.

Comment: Will, that's an interesting idea that I've never heard, in a decade of retail working.

My experience is limited to *wasted* or *dated* or *culled* and even then *wasted* isn't about *expired products*, *dated* happens automatically and *culling* is what staff do as a result of *dating*.